# postgresql extend array of json

Tags: postgresql

I have next recursive request

```
with recursive _ca as (
    select id,
           ARRAY[json_build_object('id', id, 'name', name)] as chain,
           ARRAY [id] as path
    from cost_articles
    union all
    select cost_articles.id,
           chain + ARRAY[json_build_object('id', cost_articles.id, 'name', name)] as chain,
           path + ARRAY[cost_articles.id] as path
    from cost_articles
             inner join
         _ca on cost_articles.parent_id = _ca.id
) select * from _ca
```

all fine with

```
path + ARRAY[cost_articles.id] as path
```

but with json I got

```
ERROR: operator does not exist: json[] + json[]
```

What is correct way to append to `json[]` in postgresql ?

Comment: `path + ARRAY[cost_articles.id]` is **not** "fine" - the concatenation operator for arrays is `||` not `+`. Just use `||` in both cases and it should be fine

Answer (score 0):

thanks to "a_horse_with_no_name" user

next works fine

```
with recursive _ca as (
    select id,
           ARRAY[json_build_object('id', id, 'name', name)] as chain,
           ARRAY [id] as path
    from cost_articles
    union all
    select cost_articles.id,
            chain || ARRAY[json_build_object('id', cost_articles.id, 'name', cost_articles.name)] as chain,
           path || ARRAY[cost_articles.id] as path
    from cost_articles
             inner join
         _ca on cost_articles.parent_id = _ca.id
) select * from _ca where array_length(path, 1) > 2
```